# Stats: Why is this result significant but this other one not significant?

Tags: probability, statistics

I test correlation coefficients $r$ for significant deviation from 0 using the resulting $t$ statistic. The result of two-tailed tests:

$r=0.04$, $n=300$, $P=0.4900657$ (not significant)

versus

$r=0.18$, $n=168$, $P=0.01955645$ (significant)

I do not understand why there is such a huge difference in significance here.

Comment: Usually a cutoff is used to decide whether or not to call something "significant".  This cutoff is somewhat arbitrary.  Usually it is taken to be either $0.05$ or $0.01$.  What is the cutoff in your context?

Comment: What test are you applying? From the looks of it, the approximating $t$-test for correlation coefficients. – For a tentative answer, the correlation in the second case is larger by a factor of 4.5, while the sample size is only half as large. The effect size in the second case is therefore larger by a factor of approximately $4.5 / \sqrt{300/168} = 3.4$, which can easily explain the change in the $p$-value.

Comment: Are you saying you don't understand why the first is $0.4900657$, or are you saying you don't understand why $0.4900657$ is not considered significant?

Comment: That is right.  I don't know why you'd expect the first one to be similar to the second one, since $r$ and $n$ are very different.  Your intuition should not be telling you that they should be the same.  Now if the second one was $r=0.041$ and $n=299$ and the $p$-values were that different, then that would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @ArukaJ, what test are you applying?

Comment: @ArukaJ, yes that is what it means. See my answer for a visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the underlying data are normally distributed, to test the correlation coefficient $r$ for significant deviation from 0, it is transformed into a $t$-statistic:
$$
t = r ~ \sqrt\frac{n-2}{1 - r^2}.
$$
This statistic is $t$-distributed with $n-2$ degrees of freedom. For your data:
$$
t = 0.69 \text{ with } 298 \text{ degrees of freedom}
$$
for test 1 and
$$
t = 2.36 \text{ with } 166 \text{ degrees of freedom}
$$
for test 2.

For these large numbers of degrees of freedom, the $t$-distribution is well approximated by the standard normal distribution, or $z$ variate. This comes in handy, because we can visualize both results in a common plot

[image]

where blue stands for the statistic for test 1 and red for the statistic for test 2. As you can see, the area under the curve to the right of the respective line, which defines the $p$-value, is much smaller for test 2 than for test 1, even though the line is only further right by a factor of 3.41. That is because the resulting cumulative distribution function is highly nonlinear.

For a two-tailed test, of course the respective areas have to be multiplied by 2, or equivalently the corresponding area on the left has to be added.